# R Shiny, subset from user input. mget() not returning value

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, shiny, subset

Below is my sample code. I would like the data frame to subset based on the user selected input for "Names", but if the user has selected "All Names", then the data frame will remain the same. The mget() function doesn't recognize the value of "All Names", but when I perform this outside of Shiny it works.

```
l <- NULL;
l$name <- c('b','c','d','b','b','d','c')
l$age <- c(20,20,21,21,20,22,22)
l <- as.data.frame(l)
l <- as_data_frame(l)
l$name <- as.character(l$name)

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){

assign('All Names',unique(sort(l$name)))
data <- reactive(l[which(l$name %in% mget(input$name, ifnotfound = 
input$name)[[1]]),])


output$table1 <- renderTable(data())
output$text1 <- renderPrint(input$name)


})

ui <-shinyUI(fluidPage(
selectInput("name", "Choose Name", choices=c("All Names", 
unique(sort(l$name))))
,tableOutput("table1"),
textOutput("text1")
))

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful!

Comment: not sure why you use `mget()`: `data <- reactive(l[which(l$name %in% get(input$name)),])` works for me,...

Comment: @Jamie: Your code as shown works for me